# python can't find module speech_recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

So I installed the speech_recognition library but when I try to import it it says it can't find it. This is the code I'm using.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("You said: " + r.recognize(audio))
except:
    print("i didn't quite get that")
```

But when I run it it shows this.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\python
>   projects\test.py", line 1, in 
>       import speech_recognition as sr ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'

I also tested it with: "python -m speech_recognition"
and it worked just fine.

And library is installed in: Python36\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition

Comment: Looks like the module is installed in Python 3. Maybe your script is running via Python 2?

Comment: i rand it trough IDLE and the same problem occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work when you write `python test.py` or

`pathToYourPython36Executable/python.exe test.py` into your command line?

If so, you might be using a different IDLE version to where you installed the module.

Comment: So when I type "python test.py" into the cmd seems to work thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `SpeechRecognition` instead of `speech_recognition` :

```
python3 -m SpeechRecognition
```

Answer (score 0):

your own alexa ? hehehe.
no one of these work for me on mac bigsur OS
sudo pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
sudo pip3 install speechrecognition
pip3 install speechrecognition

I fix the issue on my system checking where i installed the pkg

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

checking the path:

```
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Check where is the pkg:

```
python3 -m SpeechRecognition
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: No module named SpeechRecognition
```

Using pop install i got it, different paths

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
Requirement already satisfied: speechrecognition in /Users/paul/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (3.8.1)
```

So i manually copy the pkgs to the path where i needed:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade speechrecognition
Requirement already satisfied: speechrecognition in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages (3.8.1)
paul@MacBook-Air-de-Paul git % ls -lstr /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x    9 root  wheel   288 Jan 30 00:12 Pillow-8.1.0.dist-info
0 drwxr-xr-x  103 root  wheel  3296 Jan 30 00:12 PIL
0 drwxr-xr-x    9 root  wheel   288 Jan 30 00:15 pip-21.0.1.dist-info
0 drwxr-xr-x    7 root  wheel   224 Jan 30 00:15 pip
0 drwxr-xr-x   10 root  wheel   320 Mar  3 11:56 speech_recognition
0 drwxr-xr-x   12 root  wheel   384 Mar  3 11:56 SpeechRecognition-3.8.1.dist-info

sudo cp -r /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/

sudo cp -r /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/SpeechRecognition-3.8.1.dist-info /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
```